# Declaring the inputs property within the Angular @Component Decorator?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-material

I'm studying the Angular Material Button code and I noticed that within the `@Component` there a declared `inputs` property.

What is this for?  The description says:

> inputs - list of class property names to data-bind as component inputs

So I assume it's complementary to the `@Input()` property declarations ... But I've never seen it used anywhere else, so just curious why they are declaring it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it is indeed the same thing as marking your input as @Input(), all of the components metadata (such as HostBinding, Output, ....) can be described in the @Component decorator, but the decorator way is usually the preferred one.